# pyspark - what is the real use of "col" function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am yet to find the real use of "col" function, so far, I am seeing the same impact with using col or without using col function. Can someone elborate an use case which can only be done with "col" function.

Both return the same result.So, what is the real need of "col" function. I understood from the documentation, it retruns the col type.

```
employeesDF. \
    select(upper("first_name"), upper("last_name")). \
    show()

employeesDF. \
    select(upper(col("first_name")), upper(col("last_name"))). \
    show()
```

Answer (score 3):

In some cases the functions take column *names* aka strings as input or column types for example as you have above in select. A select is always going to return a dataframe of columns so supporting both input types makes sense. It is much more common to select using just the column name however.

In many situations though there is a big difference between (String) columnName and col(string) and you have to be explicit. For example say you have something like

```
when(col("my_col").isNull()).otherwise("other_col")
```

In that expression you would be returning the literal string "other_col" when "my_col" is null instead of the *value* from "other_col".

Comment: would you mind illustraing with an example where it is really needed to use col vs string which otherwise might not work

Comment: The above is an example. Often you want the value of another column if your current column is null. In the above example the "coder" likely would have meant to use `.otherwise(col('other_col'))` instead of `.otherwise('other_col')`. The first gives the value of the other column, the latter gives you a literal value 'other_col'. If that doesn't cover an example you are looking for could you clarify?